self-reference mutate in R
Hellow, I'm trying to build a tibble by a mutate operation that needs a self reference filter.
My objectie is to get the maximum value of a variable for all the available values of that variable that have a datetime greater than the datetime of the calculation row.
The only way I have achieved to handel it is by the following code using a for loop:
for(row in 1:nrow(df)){
  df[row, "result"] <- df %>%
    filter(datetime > df[row, "datetime"]) %>%
    pull(variable) %>%
    max(.)
}

The problem is that it is very slow and takes a long time to run. ¿is there a tydier way to do this, or any more efficient way?

Please share a minimal reproducible example of your data along with your expected output.

This approach should be pretty efficient. I reverse the data, and by group take the cumulative max, and then take the lag of that. Once back in order, that will show the largest remaining value after the current one, within the current group. Note NA's at the last observation per group, since there are no later observations to take the max of.
set.seed(42)
n = 10
df <- data.frame(datetime = as.POSIXct("2024-08-13 12:00", tz = "UCT") + 
                   runif(n, max = 1E6),
                 variable = sample(1:1E3, n, TRUE),
                 group = sample(letters[1:3], n, TRUE))

df |>
  arrange(group, desc(datetime)) |>
  mutate(future_max = lag(cummax(variable)), .by = group) |>
  arrange(group, datetime)


Result
           
              datetime variable group future_max
1  2024-08-15 01:24:26      532     a        839
2  2024-08-16 19:28:59      839     a        410
3  2024-08-19 12:11:35      165     a        410
4  2024-08-21 02:29:52      410     a        356
5  2024-08-23 02:40:47      356     a         NA
6  2024-08-21 15:51:04      882     b         NA
7  2024-08-20 22:15:45      601     c        622
8  2024-08-22 00:36:28      622     c        303
9  2024-08-24 02:06:46      303     c         24
10 2024-08-24 08:17:55       24     c         NA

It's decently fast, so it's still ~1 sec with n = 10M.

Note that running the code on the post on your data does not yield the same result. Am I missing anything?

@B.ChristianKamgang - Sys.time() returns the current time according to your computer. Unless you run the code at the same start time that the reprex was run, your results will differ every time. If you replace Sys.time() with something like as.POSIXct("2024-08-15 00:11:26"), the result will be the same each time.

I see what you mean but what I am saying is different. Running your code and the code in the post on the same data gives different results. So I am not talking about the code for generating the data you used but the code to solve the problem.

Updated. @b-christian-kamgang, still seeing different results? The only thing I can think of might be a plyr/dplyr conflict, or you're using dplyr from before Feb 2023 when .by was added in v1.1.0? That allows a better syntax than the prior group_by |> mutate |> ungroup syntax.

You can solve your problem as fallow:
# way 1: Using data.table

library(data.table)

setDT(df, key="variable")  # turn df into data.table and sort it by `variable`
df[, result := last(df$variable[df$datetime > datetime]), by=.(datetime)]

# or df[, result := df[datetime>d2, last(variable)], by=.(d2=datetime)]



# way 2: Using dplyr

library(dplyr)

df = arrange(df, variable)
df |> 
  group_by(datetime) |> 
  mutate(result = last(df$variable[df$datetime > first(datetime)])) |> 
  ungroup()

